# If a non-muslim recites the Shahadah with little or no imaan, will his/her Shahadah be accepted?

Tags: imaan, shahada

*The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said: "On the Day of Resurrection, I will intercede and say, 'O my Lord! Admit into Paradise (even) those who have faith equal to a mustard seed in their hearts.'" - Sahih Al-Bukhari, Volume 9, Hadith 600*

"*On the Day of Judgment, We shall set up scales of justice so that no one will be dealt with unjustly in any way; even if someone has an act as small as a grain of a mustard seed, We will bring it to account, and sufficient are We to settle the accounts.*" - The Holy Quran, 21:47

I'm asking this question because according to Quran, Allah knows what's in your heart. So if a man's heart is 90% disbelief and 10% belief and he recites Shahadah based on his 10% of belief, will Allah accept his Shahadah?

For example: Suppose a non-muslim has doubts about Islam and Muhammad's (pbuh) prophethood. He thinks Islam might not be the true religion and Muhammad (pbuh) might not be a prophet. But a small part of him believes that Islam might be the truth. So, he says "I will recite Shahadah just in case Islam is the truth". Will Allah accept his Shahadah?

If the imaan of this non-muslim is equal to a mustard seed, will Allah accept his Shahadah? Will he become a muslim?

Comment: How can we know whether a person who says or recites the shahada say it with no ir little Imaan? We can only judge what we see whether this would be accepted or not is up to Allah.

Answer (score 1):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions,

The example you stated refers to the Hypocrisy "Nifaq" or people as [Munafiqun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munafiqun)

> Of the people there are some who say: "We believe in Allah and the
>   Last Day;" but they do not (really) believe. (Surah Al-Baqara, 8)

**When they meet those who believe, they say: "We believe;" but when they are alone with their evil ones, they say: "We are really with you: We (were) only jesting." (Surah Al-Baqara, 14)**

> That is because they believed, then disbelieved, therefore their
>   hearts are sealed, so they understand not. (Al-Munafiqun 63:3)

Rasulullah peace be upon him has mentioned some signs of such hypocites.

> 'Abdullah ibn 'Amr narrated that the Prophet (SAW) said, "If anyone
>   has four characteristics, he is a pure hypocrite, and if anyone has
>   one of them, he has an aspect of hypocrisy until he gives it up:
>   whenever he is trusted, he betrays his trust; whenever he speaks, he
>   lies; when he makes an agreement, he breaks it; and when he quarrels,
>   he deviates from the truth by speaking falsely." [al-Bukhari (34) and
>   Muslim (58)]

Now the Hadith you have referred does not comply with your given example and would not be considered under that context because in this hadith here having faith equal to a mustard seed does not necessary mean that along that faith he also has hypocrisy as Faith increases or decreases.

It was narrated that Abu Darda' said:
**"Faith increases and decreases."(Ibn Majah)**

It was narrated that Jundub bin 'Abdullah said:

> "We were with the Prophet (ﷺ), and we were strong youths, so we
>   learned faith before we learned Qur'an. Then we learned Qur'an and our
>   faith increased thereby."(Ibn Majah)

Now regarding your last sentence would Allah swt accept the shahadah with small faith so yes Allah swt would accept the Shahadah as faith could increase or decrease and shahadah includes witnessing and also believing on it.

Allah swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: I wasn't referring to hypocrisy. Suppose I'm a non-muslim. And for no reason, I decide to become a muslim. I tell myself: "No matter what happens, I will always follow Muhammad". However, I have a lot of doubt in my heart. But I still recite the shahadah despite all these doubts. Would Allah accept my Shahadah?

Comment: Then It depends on some conditions that whether are these really doubts or waswaas from shaitan but the doubts you are mentioning are the signs of a hypocite and Allah swt is the only supreme Power who could decide these matters related to aqaaid and acceptance of shahadah because  we do not know the condition in the hearts but Allah swt knows.

Comment: The problem is that I've had doubts for so long that I slowly started to feel detached from Islam. I couldn't find any solutions for these doubts. So I talked to my parents about it and they said that I shouldn't worry about doubts. Instead, I should just follow Islam blindly. So I took their advice. I recited the Shahadah again. Every time I had doubts, I told myself "This is just waswas from shaytan". After a while, I started feeling better. But my question is: Did Allah accept my new shahadah? When I recited the shahadah, I had a lot of doubts but I chose to ignore them as waswas of shaytan

Comment: Yeah they would be accepted these are waswas from shaitan so you need to ignore then see also this http://www.sunnah.com/muslim/52/62 following good company with pious people and reciting ayat al kursi after every prayers would protect from waswaas of shaytan In Sha Allah.

Comment: But isn't Shahadah supposed to be proclaimed with a pure heart? According to many Islamic websites, one of the conditions of Shahadah is certainty. That means I can't have a single doubt. If I have a lot of doubts in my heart, why would Shahadah be accepted?

Comment: http://sunnahonline.com/library/beliefs-and-methodology/53-conditions-of-la-ilaha-illa-allah

Comment: http://al-mustaqeem.tripod.com/id83.html

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/12295

Comment: All these websites say I can't have doubts during Shahadah. Then why would Allah accept my Shahadah?

Comment: which country you reside in?

Comment: do you have skype id

Comment: No but I can open one. But I prefer to stay anonymous. Why do we need to skype exactly?

Comment: I guess the problem here is the lacking of knowledge and love.

Comment: You might have to elaborate a bit. I didn't really understand that.

Comment: you mentioned that you have doubt about the prophethood of Rasulullah salAllahu alehe wasallam you need to know him and learn about it you would fall in love with him indeed there were some who asked him for the miracles so that they could feel more faith.

Comment: Brother, I've read a lot about him. I love his character. I love his lifestyle. I want to follow his way of life until I die. I'm just having a hard time convincing myself that he received divine revelations from Allah.

Comment: I think we should continue discussing this issue in chat. I've opened a chatroom a few days ago about my problem. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47253/doubts-about-islam